# How to disable Content-type check in Apigility?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, content-type, laminas-api-tools

There is a `ContentTypeFilterListener` listener that checks `content-type` headers in Apigility. I do not need it and is often causing an error message:

> Invalid content-type specified.

Is there any way to completely disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ContentTypeFilterListener is attached to the `EventManager` [here in the Module.php on line 46](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-content-negotiation/blob/master/Module.php#L46) with the `attachAggregate` method:

```
$em->attachAggregate($services->get('ZF\ContentNegotiation\ContentTypeFilterListener'));
```

This means you can also detach it again with `detachAggregate`:

```
$em->detachAggregate($services->get('ZF\ContentNegotiation\ContentTypeFilterListener'));
```

You should be able to do this after it has been attached.